# Windows Docker Wax Dev failing to build eosio.token contract

Tags: cleos, eosio.token, docker

Im installing the Wax Dev docker container via:

```
docker run -it --name waxdev -v c:\wax:/wax waxteam/dev bash
```

I then go to run the basic tutorial of creating a simple EOSIO.token from https://developers.eos.io/welcome/v2.2/tutorials/build_your_own_eosio_token

When I get to the point of "Build And Deploy The newt Smart Contract" when I run the following command:

```
eosio-cpp -abigen -abigen_output=newt.abi -o newt.wasm newt.cpp
```

I get the following error:

```
/tmp/newt.cpp:1:10: fatal error: './newt.hpp' file not found
#include "./newt.hpp"
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
/usr/local/eosio.cdt/bin/wasm-ld: error: cannot open /tmp/newt.cpp.o: No such file or directory
```

Is there anything I'm missing here? Google possible permission issues. It just doesn't seem to want to find the header file newt.hpp.

Answer (score 0):

After continuing to search overnight I found the following issue registered against the eosio.cdt github: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/issues/489

You just need to include the -I. after the abigen